# Htaccess rewrite url in browser but dont affect the page (appearance url change only)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with a problem trying to rewrite a url without changeing its content.

I want to display in browser url a different url, but the content still the same

My url is `http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/frtcrwl/health_check/report/578/leasingautomobile.ro`

And i wanna change it to `http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/578/leasingautomobile.ro`

What i've done:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^frtcrwl/health_check/report/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Doesnt work... Any help?

**EDIT**

578 in the url is dynamic, also the "leasingautomobile.ro"

**EDIT #2**

Final code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(audit-seo)/frtcrwl/health_check/report/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Still not working as expected yet as it throws error 404. Can the path remain unchanged? Coz the url in browser link now is perfect. Thanks to @anubhava till now

Comment: Think you need to swap around your RewriteRule. It's pattern first, then replacement, e.g. something like this (don't quote me though): `RewriteRule ^/audit-seo/ /audit-seo/frtcrwl/health_check/report/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]`: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: @justbaron Nope, it doesnt work. Does not change the url, only the path and it throws 404 now

Comment: When you enter manualy, witch path is working? `http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/frtcrwl/health_check/report/578/leasingautomobile.ro` or `http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/578/leasingautomobile.ro`?

Comment: Yes, but **without** any rewrite rule, whitch one is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to this and retest inside `frtcrwl/.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /audit-seo/frtcrwl/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(audit-seo/frtcrwl)/health_check/report/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^\d+/[^/]+/?$ index.php?/health_check/report/$0 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. You're like a god for htaccess :D 
Your code works, but i found something strange using 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]

Comment: It seems like it doesnt work as these options overwrite your code. Can it be fixed to do what i expect and keeping the options too?

Comment: Ok, i put it over my code and it's working now but it doesnt seem to be a valid page (404). Is there a way of keeping the current directory path but showing different url?

Comment: did that, cleared my browser cache and used your code, there's a 404 error and the url in browser url isnt changed anymore :(

Comment: Nope, i'd like its content to be shown on this link: http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/578/leasingautomobile.ro ... So i just wanna hide "health_check/report/" directory from url but the link must be still available. Also, the full link shall redirect to this one without health_check/report/

Comment: Your first answer did that, redirect the long link including "health_check/report" to the one without these directories in url, but i got 404 as the real path was modified too

Comment: ok try my updated answer now. Is this .htaccess located inside `audit-seo/` directory?

Comment: It's located in frtcrwl directory

Comment: You need to move your .htaccess to `audit-seo/` directory and make sure there is no .htaccess in `frtcrwl` directory. Did you test my changes?

Comment: Also make sure `index.php` also resides in `audit-seo/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138651/discussion-between-anubhava-and-ozzie).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be abble to access `http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/frtcrwl/health_check/report/578/leasingautomobile.ro` from `http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/578/leasingautomobile.ro` you can use the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^audit-seo/(.+)$ audit-seo/frtcrwl/health_check/report/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your code doesnt work... it doesnt change the url

Comment: can you check anubhava's comments made by me? His code does change the url but it also change the path too. And i dont need to do that as it will throw 404

Comment: Nope, it does change the path only, the path to load but the url stay unchanged

Comment: I changed my answer. You can now access your page `http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/frtcrwl/health_check/report/578/leasingautomobile.ro` from `http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/578/leasingautomobile.ro`.

Comment: Still 404 using latest source code with link: http://fortin.agency/audit-seo/578/leasingautomobile.ro

Comment: You have a other problem. My answer is correct for the URL rewriting. Please check your logs to see what appends.